# Android ADB Wifi connection lost/reset

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I'm using the Android wifi ADB plugin for Android Studio to connect my phone to my laptop for development purposes. The plug-in is great and does what it's supposed to.
However, I have to set up the ADB via USB every time I start Android Studio. 
Clicking on the plug in icon states that there are no connected devices and to review my USB connection.
This also happens if I don't use the ADB for some time.
Is there any way to connect via wifi seamlessly?

Comment: What do you do to `set up the ADB via USB`. Something on the PC or on the device?

Comment: @Robert I connect the phone to the computer, wait for it to detect properly and then launch the app from within Android Studio

Comment: But you wrote that usually you get the message `that there are no connected devices`. What do you to to solve this problem?

Comment: @Robert I wait for the device to be detected properly on the computer, and then I launch the plug-in. It shows Device Connected and from then on I can launch the app via wifi. As I get it, the plug-in needs to connect via USB once after every restart.

Comment: Connecting device via wifi using ADBTool is very easy. Please check may be it will helps to you.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbtool/
In Tools menu you can find Connect using WIFI. Please check the video to know how to use this tool

Comment: @KiranRajam I wanted to know if there was anyway that I could bypass having to establish the connection using USB first. I wanted to connect everytime via WIFI.

Comment: No need to connect every time. But if you restart the device or PC then only you should connect again. Please check the ADBTool demo video and documentation.

Comment: @KiranRajam That's exactly what I meant. I guess there's no other way. I'm at work, so can't check right now. What happens if I restart Android Studio?

Comment: Dear Soumyadeep Paul, I am talking about ADBTool (open source tool) and this tool has no relation with AndroidStudio. Using this tool you can connect device via wifi even with out launching Android studio. Please check this tool and documentation and then let me know if it is satisfied your requirement or not.

Comment: @KiranRajam Oh ok. I will definitely check it out.

Comment: @KiranRajam I tried out your application. It's a powerful tool but it still doesn't solve my problem. Even if I use your application to connect my phone to laptop over Wi-Fi, it STILL needs the devices to be connected via USB for the initial bridge connection. After connecting once, I can connect or run other process over my Wi-Fi, until I restart any one of the device OR I disconnect one of the devices from the Wi-Fi connection.
So, your tool provides the same features as already provided by the Plug-In mentioned in the original post.

Comment: you can check the file at https://gist.github.com/kamleshkarwande/fe3edd5d13757fcedd457ac4c0953a97